# how to get text right justified in tkinter listbox?

Tags: tkinter

How to get text right justified in tkinter listbox.  The text in list box is left justified by default. Is there a way where I can get is right justified for certain items in listbox?  Please note that only few items should be right justified and not all.

Comment: Have you tried `justify='right'`?

Comment: @stovfl: what do you mean by that? The listbox doesn't support a `justify` option.

Comment: @stovfl: I stand corrected. Thanks. I didn't realize they were on tk 8.6. 8.5 doesn't support that option.

Comment: @BryanOakley As for now, we don't know if the OP uses `tk 8.6`.

Comment: yes, I have tried justify='right'.  What I am looking for is that only few items should appear on right.  Rest items should be left

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter.Listbox(..., justify='right')`

> **Note**: Bryan Oakley stated, needs at least tk 8.6

[image]

---

**Reference**:

- [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AdmirableSnappyKeys#main.py)
- [justify](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/options.htm#M-justify)
  When there are multiple lines of text displayed in a widget, this option determines how the lines line up with each other. Must be one of `left`, `center`, or `right`.
  Left means that the lines' left edges all line up, center means that the lines' centers are aligned, and right means that the lines' right edges line up.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lb = tk.Listbox(root, justify='right')
lb.pack()

for n in range(10):
  lb.insert(tk.END, f'label {n}')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you put only label 6 and label 8 on right side?

Comment: @santoshkumar: No, it's all or nothing. You can use the `Text` or `Canvas` or `Grid` widget, there you are free to place every line different.

Comment: [Text - Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/UnequaledMediocreGlueware#main.py)